# Using the apple-app-site-association file with an azure static-web-app

Tags: deep-linking, azure-configuration, azure-static-web-app, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

I am using an Azure static web app to host a website. I want to host the apple file on the backend for deep linking. I am running into the problem however that the apple documentation requires there is no extension on the file when it is uploaded. I have tried to override the content-type / mime methods to "application/json" via route rules, general headers, and extension rules. Nothing seems to change this file from being retrieved with the content type "application/octet-stream". Any guidance on how to get these two implementations to work together would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file metadata to set the content type.

Are you using CloudFront? If so, be sure to invalidate the cache for this file.